# Why has POST git-receive-pack (x bytes) doubled in size between pushes to two different repositories?

Tags: git

Using Sourcetree with BitBucket, I push to two repositories (different teams are working on them and the two instances should be kept separate) and I noticed that the push to the second repository (which I do immediately after the push to the first repository has completed) results in a `POST git-receive-pack (x bytes)` that is doubled in size.

For those of you wondering why the filesize is so huge: it is an R environment consisting of several `data.frame` and `list` objects.

This is what I get:

`Push to first repository: POST git-receive-pack (65432783 bytes)`

`Push to second repository: POST git-receive-pack (130865566 bytes)`

Why is this happening?  How can I avoid it?

Comment: I guess that in the second case also other objects not jet in the remote repositories got send along with the new commit.

Comment: But I waited until the first push was complete before initiating the second push, so how can that be?

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing to two *different* repositories, why do you expect the sizes to be the same?

Remember, `git push` pushes *commits* (not files!).  Your Git calls up another Git, and they have a little conversation: your Git says "hey, I have commit X, it needs commit W before it, do you have X or W?"  They say "I have W but not X" so your Git sends X.  Or, they say "I have neither X nor W" so your Git says "well, OK, W needs V first, do you have V?"  This goes on until your Git finds a commit that you both share, or finds that it's sending commit A that *doesn't* need any previous commit, whichever occurs first; then your Git packages up everything you have that they don't, and sends it.

So, if pushing to repo R1 produces a pack of size S1, and pushing to repo R2 produces a pack of size S2, and the sizes differ, that means that what R1 had is different from what R2 had.  If S1 < S2, R2 clearly had fewer commits so your Git must deliver more.

Note that if you connect repo R2 to repo R1, R2 can get those same commits directly from R1, once you have sent them from R1.  This might be more efficient.  It does, however, require that you be *able* to connect R2 to R1.